# How to run NOT elevated in Vista (.NET)

Tags: .net, windows-vista, uac, elevation

I have an application that I have to run as Administrator.

One small part of that application is to start other applications with Process.Start

The started applications will also be run as administrators, but I'd rather see them run as the 'normal' user.

How do I accomplish that?

/johan/

Comment: Details, including sample code, here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2009/06/06/faq-how-do-i-start-a-program-as-the-desktop-user-from-an-elevated-app.aspx

Comment: The accepted answer worked for me at the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you de-elevate privileges for a child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173630/how-do-you-de-elevate-privileges-for-a-child-process)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The WinSafer API's allow a process to be launched as a limited, normal, or elevated user.

**Sample Usage:**

```
CreateSaferProcess(@"calc.exe", "", SaferLevel.NormalUser);
```

**Source code:**

```
//http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2004/10/28/602.aspx
public static void CreateSaferProcess(String fileName, String arguments, SaferLevel saferLevel)
{
   IntPtr saferLevelHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

   //Create a SaferLevel handle to match what was requested
   if (!WinSafer.SaferCreateLevel(
         SaferLevelScope.User, 
         saferLevel, 
         SaferOpen.Open, 
         out saferLevelHandle, 
         IntPtr.Zero))
   {
      throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
   }
   try
   {
      //Generate the access token to use, based on the safer level handle.
      IntPtr hToken = IntPtr.Zero;

      if (!WinSafer.SaferComputeTokenFromLevel(
            saferLevelHandle,  // SAFER Level handle
            IntPtr.Zero,       // NULL is current thread token.
            out hToken,        // Target token
            SaferTokenBehaviour.Default,      // No flags
            IntPtr.Zero))      // Reserved
      {
         throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
      }
      try
      {
         //Now that we have a security token, we can lauch the process
         //using the standard CreateProcessAsUser API
         STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
         si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
         si.lpDesktop = String.Empty;

         PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

         // Spin up the new process
         Boolean bResult = Windows.CreateProcessAsUser(
               hToken,
               fileName,
               arguments,
               IntPtr.Zero, //process attributes
               IntPtr.Zero, //thread attributes
               false, //inherit handles
               0, //CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
               IntPtr.Zero, //environment
               null, //current directory
               ref si, //startup info
               out pi); //process info

         if (!bResult)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

         if (pi.hProcess != IntPtr.Zero)
            Windows.CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

         if (pi.hThread != IntPtr.Zero)
            Windows.CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
      }
      finally
      {
         if (hToken != IntPtr.Zero)
            Windows.CloseHandle(hToken);
      }
   }
   finally
   {
      WinSafer.SaferCloseLevel(saferLevelHandle);
   }
}
```

**P/Invoke declarations:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PInvoke
{
   public class WinSafer
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// The SaferCreateLevel function opens a SAFER_LEVEL_HANDLE.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="scopeId">The scope of the level to be created.</param>
      /// <param name="levelId">The level of the handle to be opened.</param>
      /// <param name="openFlags">Must be SaferOpenFlags.Open</param>
      /// <param name="levelHandle">The returned SAFER_LEVEL_HANDLE. When you have finished using the handle, release it by calling the SaferCloseLevel function.</param>
      /// <param name="reserved">This parameter is reserved for future use. IntPtr.Zero</param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern bool SaferCreateLevel(SaferLevelScope scopeId, SaferLevel levelId, SaferOpen openFlags,
            out IntPtr levelHandle, IntPtr reserved);

      /// <summary>
      /// The SaferComputeTokenFromLevel function restricts a token using restrictions specified by a SAFER_LEVEL_HANDLE.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="levelHandle">SAFER_LEVEL_HANDLE that contains the restrictions to place on the input token. Do not pass handles with a LevelId of SAFER_LEVELID_FULLYTRUSTED or SAFER_LEVELID_DISALLOWED to this function. This is because SAFER_LEVELID_FULLYTRUSTED is unrestricted and SAFER_LEVELID_DISALLOWED does not contain a token.</param>
      /// <param name="inAccessToken">Token to be restricted. If this parameter is NULL, the token of the current thread will be used. If the current thread does not contain a token, the token of the current process is used.</param>
      /// <param name="outAccessToken">The resulting restricted token.</param>
      /// <param name="flags">Specifies the behavior of the method.</param>
      /// <param name="lpReserved">Reserved for future use. This parameter should be set to IntPtr.EmptyParam.</param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern bool SaferComputeTokenFromLevel(IntPtr levelHandle, IntPtr inAccessToken,
            out IntPtr outAccessToken, SaferTokenBehaviour flags, IntPtr lpReserved);

      /// <summary>
      /// The SaferCloseLevel function closes a SAFER_LEVEL_HANDLE that was opened by using the SaferIdentifyLevel function or the SaferCreateLevel function.</summary>
      /// <param name="levelHandle">The SAFER_LEVEL_HANDLE to be closed.</param>
      /// <returns>TRUE if the function succeeds; otherwise, FALSE. For extended error information, call GetLastWin32Error.</returns>
      [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern bool SaferCloseLevel(IntPtr levelHandle);
   } //class WinSafer

   /// <summary>
   /// Specifies the behaviour of the SaferComputeTokenFromLevel method
   /// </summary>
   public enum SaferTokenBehaviour : uint
   {
      /// <summary></summary>
      Default = 0x0,
      /// <summary>If the OutAccessToken parameter is not more restrictive than the InAccessToken parameter, the OutAccessToken parameter returns NULL.</summary>
      NullIfEqual = 0x1,
      /// <summary></summary>
      CompareOnly = 0x2,
      /// <summary></summary>
      MakeInert = 0x4,
      /// <summary></summary>
      WantFlags = 0x8
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// The level of the handle to be opened.
   /// </summary>
   public enum SaferLevel : uint
   {
      /// <summary>Software will not run, regardless of the user rights of the user.</summary>
      Disallowed = 0,
      /// <summary>Allows programs to execute with access only to resources granted to open well-known groups, blocking access to Administrator and Power User privileges and personally granted rights.</summary>
      Untrusted = 0x1000,
      /// <summary>Software cannot access certain resources, such as cryptographic keys and credentials, regardless of the user rights of the user.</summary>
      Constrained = 0x10000,
      /// <summary>Allows programs to execute as a user that does not have Administrator or Power User user rights. Software can access resources accessible by normal users.</summary>
      NormalUser = 0x20000,
      /// <summary>Software user rights are determined by the user rights of the user.</summary>
      FullyTrusted = 0x40000
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// The scope of the level to be created.
   /// </summary>
   public enum SaferLevelScope : uint
   {
      /// <summary>The created level is scoped by computer.</summary>
      Machine = 1,
      /// <summary>The created level is scoped by user.</summary>
      User = 2
   }

   public enum SaferOpen : uint
   {
      Open = 1
   }
} //namespace PInvoke
```

Comment: IIRC, a process started with a Safer token still runs @ High IL if the parent process was High IL so you may have a deny admin SID in the token, but its not a normal user token

Comment: i just spied on an IE startup. It relaunches IE using CreateProcessAsUserW(), so...

Comment: What is about for RedirectStandardOutput and  RedirectStandardError ? Any sample about it ?

Comment: i also wanted to include a link to a better way: "[FAQ: How do I start a program as the desktop user from an elevated app?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2009/06/06/faq-how-do-i-start-a-program-as-the-desktop-user-from-an-elevated-app.aspx)". The common bug, and in my SAFER code above, is the faulty assumption that the the elevated application is running as me. It is incorrect to take the credentials of the running application, *"dumb it down"*, and then launch the app as the same user but "standard".

Comment: Raymond Chen [on the same topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/11/18/10468726.aspx).

Comment: @GSerg Which is great. But i'm concerned about the case when Explorer isn't around (e.g. a kiosk). and what about Server Core, when there is no Explorer?

Comment: @IanBoyd I'm probably not experienced enough to answer that (I was hunting down a duplicate question which is why I posted some comments as a public service too). However in the comments section for that blog entry they say [these configurations don't have UAC either](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/11/18/10468726.aspx#10469212).

Comment: just linking this here, ref for the `WinSafer` : `AdvApi` methods - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#safer_functions

Comment: also, here is MS VB.net sample project for this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VBUACSelfElevation-4c014507 <- Windows UAC self-elevation

Comment: Didn't work for me on Windows 8. The launched application (Notepad) was always elevated.

Comment: As @Anders said, this will start with High integrity level. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40687129/33080) for an example of how to modify the token to use Medium integrity level, like a normal un-elevated process.

Comment: the provided code does not compile. Can you please update

Answer (score 7):

From: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=81232

> A frequently asked question is how to
>   launch an un-elevated application from
>   an elevated process, or more
>   fundamentally, how to I launch a
>   process using my un-elevated token
>   once I’m running elevated.  Since
>   there is no direct way to do this, the
>   situation can usually be avoided by
>   launching the original application as
>   standard user and only elevating those
>   portions of the application that
>   require administrative rights.  This
>   way there is always a non-elevated
>   process that can be used to launch
>   additional applications as the
>   currently logged on desktop user. 
>   Sometimes, however, an elevated
>   process needs to get another
>   application running un-elevated.  This
>   can be accomplished by using the task
>   scheduler within Windows Vista.  The
>   elevated process can register a task
>   to run as the currently logged on
>   desktop user.

Here is an example of how to schedule the un-elevated process (again from the same link)

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//  This file is part of the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK Code Samples.
// 
//  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// 
//This source code is intended only as a supplement to Microsoft
//Development Tools and/or on-line documentation.  See these other
//materials for detailed information regarding Microsoft code samples.
// 
//THIS CODE AND INFORMATION ARE PROVIDED AS IS WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY
//KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE
//IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A
//PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

/****************************************************************************
* Main.cpp - Sample application for Task Scheduler V2 COMAPI                * Component: Task Scheduler                          
* Copyright (c) 2002 - 2003, Microsoft Corporation 
* This sample creates a task to that launches as the currently logged on deskup user. The task launches as soon as it is registered.                                                             *
****************************************************************************/
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <comutil.h>
//Include Task header files - Included in Windows Vista Beta-2 SDK from MSDN
#include <taskschd.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define CLEANUP \
pRootFolder->Release();\
        pTask->Release();\
        CoUninitialize();

HRESULT CreateMyTask(LPCWSTR, wstring);

void __cdecl wmain(int argc, wchar_t** argv)
{
wstring wstrExecutablePath;
WCHAR taskName[20];
HRESULT result;

if( argc < 2 )
{
printf("\nUsage: LaunchApp yourapp.exe" );
return;
}

// Pick random number for task name
srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
wsprintf((LPWSTR)taskName, L"Launch %d", rand());

wstrExecutablePath = argv[1];

result = CreateMyTask(taskName, wstrExecutablePath);
printf("\nReturn status:%d\n", result);

}
HRESULT CreateMyTask(LPCWSTR wszTaskName, wstring wstrExecutablePath)
{
    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Initialize COM.
TASK_STATE taskState;
int i;
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeEx failed: %x", hr );
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set general COM security levels.
    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL);

    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeSecurity failed: %x", hr );
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create an instance of the Task Service. 
    ITaskService *pService = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_TaskScheduler,
                           NULL,
                           CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                           IID_ITaskService,
                           (void**)&pService );  
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed to CoCreate an instance of the TaskService class: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Connect to the task service.
    hr = pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("ITaskService::Connect failed: %x", hr );
        pService->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the pointer to the root task folder.  This folder will hold the
    //  new task that is registered.
    ITaskFolder *pRootFolder = NULL;
    hr = pService->GetFolder( _bstr_t( L"\\") , &pRootFolder );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("Cannot get Root Folder pointer: %x", hr );
        pService->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Check if the same task already exists. If the same task exists, remove it.
    hr = pRootFolder->DeleteTask( _bstr_t( wszTaskName), 0  );

    //  Create the task builder object to create the task.
    ITaskDefinition *pTask = NULL;
    hr = pService->NewTask( 0, &pTask );

    pService->Release();  // COM clean up.  Pointer is no longer used.
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed to CoCreate an instance of the TaskService class: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }


    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the trigger collection to insert the registration trigger.
    ITriggerCollection *pTriggerCollection = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Triggers( &pTriggerCollection );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot get trigger collection: %x", hr );
  CLEANUP
        return 1;
    }

    //  Add the registration trigger to the task.
    ITrigger *pTrigger = NULL;

    hr = pTriggerCollection->Create( TASK_TRIGGER_REGISTRATION, &pTrigger );     
    pTriggerCollection->Release();  // COM clean up.  Pointer is no longer used.
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot add registration trigger to the Task %x", hr );
        CLEANUP
        return 1;
    }
    pTrigger->Release();

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Add an Action to the task.     
    IExecAction *pExecAction = NULL;
    IActionCollection *pActionCollection = NULL;

    //  Get the task action collection pointer.
    hr = pTask->get_Actions( &pActionCollection );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot get Task collection pointer: %x", hr );
        CLEANUP
        return 1;
    }

    //  Create the action, specifying that it is an executable action.
    IAction *pAction = NULL;
    hr = pActionCollection->Create( TASK_ACTION_EXEC, &pAction );
    pActionCollection->Release();  // COM clean up.  Pointer is no longer used.
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\npActionCollection->Create failed: %x", hr );
        CLEANUP
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pAction->QueryInterface( IID_IExecAction, (void**) &pExecAction );
    pAction->Release();
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\npAction->QueryInterface failed: %x", hr );
        CLEANUP
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set the path of the executable to the user supplied executable.
   hr = pExecAction->put_Path( _bstr_t( wstrExecutablePath.c_str() ) );  

    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot set path of executable: %x", hr );
        pExecAction->Release();
        CLEANUP
        return 1;
    }
    hr = pExecAction->put_Arguments( _bstr_t( L"" ) );  

   if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot set arguments of executable: %x", hr );
        pExecAction->Release();
        CLEANUP
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Save the task in the root folder.
    IRegisteredTask *pRegisteredTask = NULL;
    hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(
            _bstr_t( wszTaskName ),
            pTask,
      TASK_CREATE, 
_variant_t(_bstr_t( L"S-1-5-32-545")),//Well Known SID for \\Builtin\Users group
_variant_t(), 
TASK_LOGON_GROUP,
            _variant_t(L""),
            &pRegisteredTask);
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nError saving the Task : %x", hr );
        CLEANUP
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\n Success! Task successfully registered. " );
    for (i=0; i<100; i++)//give 10 seconds for the task to start
{
pRegisteredTask->get_State(&taskState);
if (taskState == TASK_STATE_RUNNING)
{
printf("\nTask is running\n");
break;
}
Sleep(100);
}
if (i>= 100) printf("Task didn't start\n");

    //Delete the task when done
    hr = pRootFolder->DeleteTask(
            _bstr_t( wszTaskName ),
            NULL);
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nError deleting the Task : %x", hr );
        CLEANUP
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\n Success! Task successfully deleted. " );

//  Clean up.
    CLEANUP
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The linked article moved, and no longer contains that quote. Googling for the quote finds the original article, which mentions the sample code in the "references" section of the same article. Expectedly, there is no code sample in the article. Yet another reason to put answers on Stackoverflow, not links to ansers.

Comment: The moved article is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756914.aspx ; the reference section which contains the code sample can be found under the "UAC References" link in the left-hand column. (The article has been split into several pages.)

Comment: Not really a .NET answer, even though this could point in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

Raymond Chen addressed this in his blog:

[How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=2643)

Searching in GitHub for a C# version of this code, I found the following implementation in Microsoft's **Node.js tools for Visual Studio** repository: [SystemUtilities.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/nodejstools/blob/master/Nodejs/Product/Nodejs/SharedProject/SystemUtilities.cs) (the `ExecuteProcessUnElevated` function).

Just in case the file disappears, here's the file's contents:

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft.  All Rights Reserved.  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0.  See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Microsoft.NodejsTools.SharedProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Utility for accessing window IShell* interfaces in order to use them to launch a process unelevated
    /// </summary>
    internal class SystemUtility
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// We are elevated and should launch the process unelevated. We can't create the
        /// process directly without it becoming elevated. So to workaround this, we have
        /// explorer do the process creation (explorer is typically running unelevated).
        /// </summary>
        internal static void ExecuteProcessUnElevated(string process, string args, string currentDirectory = "")
        {
            var shellWindows = (IShellWindows)new CShellWindows();

            // Get the desktop window
            object loc = CSIDL_Desktop;
            object unused = new object();
            int hwnd;
            var serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)shellWindows.FindWindowSW(ref loc, ref unused, SWC_DESKTOP, out hwnd, SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH);

            // Get the shell browser
            var serviceGuid = SID_STopLevelBrowser;
            var interfaceGuid = typeof(IShellBrowser).GUID;
            var shellBrowser = (IShellBrowser)serviceProvider.QueryService(ref serviceGuid, ref interfaceGuid);

            // Get the shell dispatch
            var dispatch = typeof(IDispatch).GUID;
            var folderView = (IShellFolderViewDual)shellBrowser.QueryActiveShellView().GetItemObject(SVGIO_BACKGROUND, ref dispatch);
            var shellDispatch = (IShellDispatch2)folderView.Application;

            // Use the dispatch (which is unelevated) to launch the process for us
            shellDispatch.ShellExecute(process, args, currentDirectory, string.Empty, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Interop definitions
        /// </summary>
        private const int CSIDL_Desktop = 0;
        private const int SWC_DESKTOP = 8;
        private const int SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH = 1;
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        private const int SVGIO_BACKGROUND = 0;
        private readonly static Guid SID_STopLevelBrowser = new Guid("4C96BE40-915C-11CF-99D3-00AA004AE837");

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39")]
        [ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
        private class CShellWindows
        {
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("85CB6900-4D95-11CF-960C-0080C7F4EE85")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        private interface IShellWindows
        {
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)]
            object FindWindowSW([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref object pvarloc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref object pvarlocRoot, int swClass, out int pHWND, int swfwOptions);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        private interface IServiceProvider
        {
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
            object QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("000214E2-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        private interface IShellBrowser
        {
            void VTableGap01(); // GetWindow
            void VTableGap02(); // ContextSensitiveHelp
            void VTableGap03(); // InsertMenusSB
            void VTableGap04(); // SetMenuSB
            void VTableGap05(); // RemoveMenusSB
            void VTableGap06(); // SetStatusTextSB
            void VTableGap07(); // EnableModelessSB
            void VTableGap08(); // TranslateAcceleratorSB
            void VTableGap09(); // BrowseObject
            void VTableGap10(); // GetViewStateStream
            void VTableGap11(); // GetControlWindow
            void VTableGap12(); // SendControlMsg
            IShellView QueryActiveShellView();
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("000214E3-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        private interface IShellView
        {
            void VTableGap01(); // GetWindow
            void VTableGap02(); // ContextSensitiveHelp
            void VTableGap03(); // TranslateAcceleratorA
            void VTableGap04(); // EnableModeless
            void VTableGap05(); // UIActivate
            void VTableGap06(); // Refresh
            void VTableGap07(); // CreateViewWindow
            void VTableGap08(); // DestroyViewWindow
            void VTableGap09(); // GetCurrentInfo
            void VTableGap10(); // AddPropertySheetPages
            void VTableGap11(); // SaveViewState
            void VTableGap12(); // SelectItem

            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
            object GetItemObject(UInt32 aspectOfView, ref Guid riid);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        private interface IDispatch
        {
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("E7A1AF80-4D96-11CF-960C-0080C7F4EE85")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        private interface IShellFolderViewDual
        {
            object Application { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] get; }
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("A4C6892C-3BA9-11D2-9DEA-00C04FB16162")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        public interface IShellDispatch2
        {
            void ShellExecute([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string File, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] object vArgs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] object vDir, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] object vOperation, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] object vShow);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement and I come to the solution to use the task scheduler service from Windows.

So, first add [the `Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper`](https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) [library to your project](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/) and use this code to create a task, configure it to run as limited user (`td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.LUA;`), register the task, run the task and after finish, delete the task.

```
// Get the service on the local machine
using (var ts = new TaskService())
{
     const string taskName = "foo";

     // Create a new task definition and assign properties
     var td = ts.NewTask();
     td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "start foo.exe as limited user";

     // Create an action that will launch foo.exe, with argument bar in workingdir C:\\
     td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("C:\\foo.exe", "bar", "C:\\"));

     td.Settings.Priority = ProcessPriorityClass.Normal;

     // run with limited token
     td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.LUA;

     td.Settings.AllowDemandStart = true;

     td.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = false;

     td.Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = false;

     // Register the task in the root folder
     var ret = ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskName, td);

     var fooTask = ts.FindTask(taskName, true);
     if (null != fooTask )
     {
         if (fooTask.Enabled)
         {
             fooTask.Run();

             Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

             // find process and wait for Exit
             var processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

             foreach(var theprocess in processlist)
             {
                 if (theprocess.ProcessName != "foo")
                    continue;

                 theprocess.WaitForExit();
                 break;
             }
         }
    }

    // Remove the task we just created
    ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask(taskName);
}
```