# Start non-elevated process from elevated process

Tags: c#, .net, uac, elevated-privileges, start-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run NOT elevated in Vista (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196949/how-to-run-not-elevated-in-vista-net)
>   [How do you de-elevate privileges for a child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173630/how-do-you-de-elevate-privileges-for-a-child-process)

My program running as an elevated process, and starting new processes with `Process.Start()`.

For security reasons, I would like to run those new processes as non-elevated.

How to do that?

Comment: I also asked and this question myself and found a solution that worked for me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173630/how-do-you-de-elevate-privileges-for-a-child-process/2785337#2785337