# Start process as limited user from elevated script

Tags: batch-file, console, uac, elevation, process-elevation

I have an elevated console running some bat files. Having this console running in elevated mode is mandatory for it to be able to perform some tasks like managing network shares, etc without asking for permissions. But sometimes the scripts also have to launch some applications which are not desired to run elevated. So we want our elevated bats to start come application in non-elevated mode. Is there any built-in way to do this on Windows? Processes were started with DOS command START up to the date.

By the way, the machine is a Windows 7 Ultimate Edition x64.

I know this isue is already discussed programatically in many questions ([this collects many of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927790/start-non-elevated-process-from-elevated-process)), but our requirements are bat scripts running on cmd, and any standalone executable that may help in our tasks, like nircmd, 7z, etc.

*Clarification: we already have a scheduled task which starts the console elevated, and elevating the console is not the issue os this answer.*

Comment: By the way, I've already read [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2006/03/02/running-as-limited-user-the-easy-way.aspx), and seems the best solution by the moment. But I'll be glad to hear other's minds.

Comment: I think PsExec is probably your simplest and most straightforward solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The built-in Windows way**: `START RUNAS ...` allows you to run a process as limited user. Here's an example:

```
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 cmd.exe
```

Anyway, there are some internal differences between the execution permissions on a process executed that way and another started from the UI with UAC enabled (explorer.exe via normal user interaction, I mean, execution from file browser or from start menu).

- On the process started via runas (right) we miss some permissions disabled:
  [image: Process Explorer screenshot showing execution permissions differences]
- On the process started via runas (right) Administrators have some permisions set over the process:
  [image: Process Explorer screenshot showing differences on user permissions over the processes]

**The Third-Party application way**: we can achieve our goal using [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/sysinternals/bb897553), a standalone executable we can find on PSTools from Windows Sysinternals. Here's an example:

```
psexec -l -d cmd.exe
```

I've looked very deep into the issue and I've noticed no difference in any of the running permissions or security flags.

From the [Microsoft Technet blogs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2006/03/02/running-as-limited-user-the-easy-way.aspx):

> PsExec use the [CreateRestrictedToken API](http://windowssdk.msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/secauthz/security/createrestrictedtoken.asp) to create a security context, called a token, that’s a stripped-down version of its own, removing administrative privileges and group membership. After generating a token that looks like one that Windows assigns to standard users Process Explorer calls CreateProcessAsUser to launch the target process with the new token.

These are the best conslussions I've managed to get after many hours of research; anyone who can provide further details will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Really not my area of expertise, but would `START RUNAS ...` or perhaps `AT` fit the bill?

Comment: good point. I've tried it with 'runas /trustlevel:0x20000 cmd.exe'. In the end it works, although I've found many things I disliked: first, when trying to exec the program, it looks for it in %path% directories, but it doesn't scan [the App Paths in the registry](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2004/04/11/111232.aspx), so for example "cmd" works, but "iexplore" doesn't. I've also detected differences in the process executive permissions when I start it this way instead of from UI. I'll go deeper and come back with the conclussions.

Comment: I'll post the complete answer by editing yours so the merit is yours. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Áxel Your solution is quite more extensive that the the original solution of Peter. You should post it as a new answer.

Comment: Hi @madth3, I suppose you've been asked to peer-review this and rejected it. Well, there are situations in which it's not clear what is the best way to do, and I proceed that way because my answer includes 'runas' and I discovered that options thanks PeterWright.