# downgrade rights of a started process

Tags: c#, process

I need to start an application from another application. It looks like I have to use the shell to do it (since I need to be able to close the launcher), but I also would like to downgrade the rights given to the launching application.

Is this possible? The launcher must run as administrator, but I'd like to have the launching application run as user.

this is how I currently run the process:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
process.StartInfo.FileName = name;

process.Start();
```

Forgive me I forgot to add a couple of details:

- I need to run it in .net 3.5 on mono
- I'd prefer to not use native code
- I need to run the launcher application in admin mode

Comment: I'd look into the "runas" verb ... to run as admin I believe you use runas with no param. I think you may be able to do the opposite

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413900/launch-a-process-under-another-users-credentials

Comment: See this answer. It recommends not starting as admin in the first place http://stackoverflow.com/a/7880040/187697

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I am now testing the "starting not as admin" solution, question is how can I start the launcher with elevated rights and redirect the output as well? It looks like I cannot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be have discussed before, check this out: [How do you de-elevate privileges for a child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173630/how-do-you-de-elevate-privileges-for-a-child-process)

Looks like an UAC elevation is strictly one-way, so the solutions are a bit gnarly, i.e. code injection into explorer and stuff like that.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18946/High-elevation-can-be-bad-for-your-application-How

Comment: theoretically I could use also the last solution, because I do not need to capture the output

Comment: rundll32.exe seems to be not reliable, I must discard the codeproject solution unluckily.

Comment: How about if you make your application in two parts then? Begin with one unprivileged boot strap part. Have that start your privileged part, and then add some mechanism for your priviledged part to communicate back to the first one to have that start the other app. Definitely more complicated though, but at least it should be reliable.

Comment: I am now testing the "starting not as admin" solution, question is how can I start the launcher with elevated rights and redirect the output as well? It looks like I cannot!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I decided to create a bootstrapper that could run the launcher as administrator, but then the application as normal user. Once the launcher is done it goes back to the bootstrap executable which launches the application.