# Run as Current logged User

Tags: c#, process, runas

I have two executables. My first is running under administrative privileges. I want to start another process with current logged in user. I don't know password of the current logged in user. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you give a bit more information as to what you are trying to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to start the process unelevated, or as an entirely different but logged on user?

Comment: if you want to retrieve the current user name or to limit privileges

Comment: How about removing Administrative privileges?

Comment: My exe running in administrative privilege will call the exe. for that i am using process as process.start in that i used verb as "runas". I got current logged in user id but the problem is i dont have password..

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173630/how-do-you-de-elevate-privileges-for-a-child-process If you only want to "de-elevate" privileges. And also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196949/how-to-run-not-elevated-in-vista-net

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by impersonating the logged on user. Here is a link which specifies 3 ways of doing this (not much of a detail though) [Run an application under current logon user's privileges](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90713/Run-an-application-under-current-logon-user-s-priv)

Comment: I already have logged on username using 'explorer.exe' but to run process in need password of currently logged in user..

Comment: There is no way to get the password of the logged in user other than ask the user. I though this was a valid question...

Comment: Yes but cant i run a process without password for verb='runas'

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know who is logged in and in this user has an active desktop, then, get process handle started by this user and grab credentials from this process. You can then sart process with those credentials

Comment: yes i got logged in user with explorer.exe user whose sessionid = 1. now how to get user credentials to start the process??