# using CreateProcessAsUser to launch a url

Tags: c#, c++, windows, uri, elevation

Recently I bumped into an issue where I need to open a webpage from an elevated application. I need the browser to be opened non elevated so I looked around and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/287072/127602)

This would definitely solve my issue except that `CreateProcessAsUser` does not accept URIs as a filename, the execution will fail with the error message being "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Can someone tell me if there is a way to launch a website through CreateProcessAsUser or if there is a similar API that does the job.. Please note that my actual application is always elevated and thus I cannot uses the usual `Process.Start()`, `CreateProcess()` or `ShellExecute()`

Answer (score 3):

There are two distinct families of functions that you will need to use to get this task done:

1. `CreateProcess` and related functions. These can be used to start a new process. You must supply a filename of an executable image.
2. `ShellExecute` and friends. These will apply verbs to files using the shell's rules for associating file classes to executables.

In order to open a URI you need to use one of the `ShellExecute` family. And in order to execute as a standard user from your elevated process, you need to use one of the `CreateProcess` family.

You cannot meet both your requirements with a single function. Your solution therefore is to use one of the `CreateProcessXXX` functions to create a process that runs as standard user. That process in turn will call `ShellExecuteXXX`. You will pass the URI as command line arguments to `CreateProcessXXX`.

You will therefore need to either create a distinct executable as your standard user launcher. Or re-use your existing executable but make it switch into launcher mode depending on the arguments that you pass it.

Comment: I am aware of that solution and was hoping for something else... will wait and see if someone can come up with something different

Comment: That's the only solution, unless you wish to re-implement `ShellExecuteXXX`. Lots of people do that, poking at the registry, but they always get it wrong in some detail or other!

Answer (score 0):

I used `CreateProcessAsUser()` with CommandLine like `cmd /c start myurl:`, then there is no need to create another executable just to call the shell execute.