# Granting admin privileges to a process

Tags: c#, pinvoke

There are lots of techniques using Win32 LogonUser() API but that requires a username & password.

Assuming the parent/invoker process has all the privileges (say a Windows Service running as localsystem), is it possible to elevate a process so that it will have admin privileges?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elevating process privilege programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically)

Comment: Let me clarify; What I'm after is to have a regular user (non-admin) to launch a process with admin rights. I could use "runas" verb to launch a process from the windows service but that would be a separate process which cannot interact with the user mode. I thought AdjustTokenPrivileges would be a solution but all samples require a username/password. Which I don't prefer...

Comment: What's wrong with using the runas verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot elevate an existing process to have admin privileges - the only way for a process to gain admin privileges is to start with them (e.g. by the user using "Run as administrator", or by using a manifest)

If your parent / invoker process is already elevated then any child processes launched will also be elevated by default (the difficult bit is starting a *non* elevated process).

See

- [Requesting administrator privileges at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418791/requesting-administrator-privileges-at-run-time)
- [How to run NOT elevated in Vista (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196949/how-to-run-not-elevated-in-vista-net)

Comment: Looks like I'm in wrong direction. Thank you for the first link.