# Visual Studio - start external program with different elevation

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010

We have an Excel addin that uses Addin Express.
To register the addin, we must run Visual Studio as administrator.
It seems that Windows 10 has some different behaviour when it comes to elevated rights/UAC than 7 did.

My question:
Is there a way to launch an external program in VS debug (such as Excel) NOT as an administrator, when VS is running as admin.

The issue is really more of an annoyance, but when you double-click an excel file it only opens in the existing/opened instance of Excel if Excel is not elevated.

So I start debugging my Addin, and in Win7 I could just double-click-to-open .xlsx files, and they'd open in the debugging instance of Excel. In Win10, it opens a new instance (not being debugged) unless I go through the 3-4 click file/open process in Excel. Not a big deal, except I do it several hundred times a day, so I'm trying to save clicks and time.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: You can create a small program to do this, see [How to run NOT elevated in Vista (.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/287072/33499). In this case you probably need to keep it running after starting the unelevated process.