# Doesn't work ShowWindow Run As Administrator

Tags: c#, showwindow

Iam writing a program for hide target program  , actually its working but , when I run the program as administrator , showWindow function doesn't work.How can I solve this problem?

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {       
            Process mbot = null;
            pHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (process.ProcessName == "mBot_vSRO110")
                {
                    mbot = process;
                }

            }            
            pHandle = mbot.MainWindowHandle;
            Thread.Sleep(100);    
        }            

        ShowWindow(pHandle, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to [User Interface Privilege Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation). Because the window is in a higher privilege process, your call is ignored.

To control an elevated process, run your own process elevated.

Comment: Thanks for everything :) , I found like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196949/how-to-run-not-elevated-in-vista-net   This is useful?

Comment: do you have any control over the target program? some programs require elevation to work.